# Assembly file save

Tags: assembly, dos

I am trying to save result of adding to file but i have some issue:

in file I do not find numbers but strange chars Can you show me where I make mistake
At start of my program i create file to store result

```
MOV AH,3CH 
MOV CX,1 ;
mov dx, result
INT 21H
mov word [filehandle],ax ;
```

Then in function which converts ASCII to decimal I try write to file

```
      dec:
      pop  dx  

      add  dx,  0x30 

      MOV AH,40H
      MOV BX, word [filehandle]
      MOV dx,  dx
      MOV CX, 1
      iNT 21H

      mov  ax,  0x0200   
      int  0x21 

      cmp  bp,  sp  
      jne  dec
```

Finally I close file

```
 MOV AH,3EH
 mov BX, word[filehandle]
 int 21h
```

Comment: What are you really trying to write to the file? `int 21h / ah=40h` expects `dx` to contain _the address of_ the data to write to the file.

Comment: In dx i got number, 1 bit so I want write this number to file.

Comment: You'd have to convert the number to a string and put the address of the string in `dx`.

Comment: Maybe but this not a problem. Problem is why I find in file strange chars?

Comment: Obviously you're going to find "strange" chars if you're not writing correct data to the file.

Comment: As Michael said, `DX` should be a pointer to your data. Put your data into memory and pass its address.

Comment: I am green with assembly can you show me how do this?

Comment: For to write an ASCII in the DL-register to a reserved memory location use:`mov [ASCII],dl` and for to get the offset address of this memory location into the DX-register use:`lea dx,ASCII` and for to reserve the memory location with the label ASCII use:`ASCII DB ?`